# Canceling an alarm in AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my code, I create an alarm as follows:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent("mypackage.START_MONITORING_SERVICE");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
long timeForNextStart = System.currentTimeMillis() + elapsedTime;
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeForNextStart, pi);
```

To cancel the alarm I do this:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("mypackage.START_MONITORING_SERVICE");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

My question is whether this is the correct way to cancel ALL alarms of the same intent. The docs say:

> Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type,
>   whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)),
>   will be canceled.

I'm not exactly sure what defines a "matching intent". If I create multiple alarms with the above code and then peform the cancel as shown, will it cancel ALL of the alarms I created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PendingIntent flag ==> PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT fourth parameters create pendingIntent instance method.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyPendingIntentService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);

    // Cancel alarms
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether this is the correct way to cancel ALL alarms of
>   the same intent?

I dont know if you aware of `requestCode`  should be unique in for each `pendingIntent`  for following syntax

```
public static PendingIntent getService (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

> I'm not exactly sure what defines a "matching intent".

Each pending intent map with its provided intent to trigger  and each request code  map with that intent .

We  can say it can be same `requestcode` for two different `pendingIntent` which ideally having two different  `intents` .

Remember , here if `PendingIntent` have a same `requestCode` for a same `intent` then it can  be override or cancel according to `int flags`

> If I create multiple alarms with the above code and then peform the
>   cancel as shown, will it cancel ALL of the alarms I created?

To create a multiple alarm you have to give a different `requestCode` with the  same `intent`  .
If you want to cancel those created alarm then you have to cancel them according `requestCode`

For example

```
To Create :

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
For (int i= 0 ; i <5 ; i++){
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TaskReminder.this, i,
                            new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeForNextStart, contentIntent);

}

To cancel :

For (int i= 0 ; i <5 ; i++){
//Note here ' i ' is the requestCode which map each pendingIntent with there provided intent 
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TaskReminder.this, i,
                            new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 alarmManager.cancel(contentIntent);

}
```